# jQuery change CSS of child item

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery snippet that selects a div based on a selected class and then apply some CSS to it

```
<div class="slc_option wrapper">
<a class="myanchor" title="My Anchor Title 1">My Link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="slc_option wrapper selected">
    <a class="myanchor" title="My Anchor Title 2">My Link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="slc_option wrapper">
    <a class="myanchor" title="My Anchor Title 3">My Link 3</a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q73x6ozs/)

```
jQuery(".slc_option.wrapper.selected").css({"background-color":"red","height":"50px"});
```

I would now like to change the CSS for the .myanchor class itself.  Anyone have an example I can see?

Comment: you just add .myanchor to your already writing css binding element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".slc_option.wrapper.selected .myanchor").css({"background-color":"red","height":"50px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    jQuery(".slc_option.wrapper.selected .myanchor")
.css({"background-color":"red","height":"50px"});
```

Or

```
    jQuery(".slc_option.wrapper.selected>.myanchor")
.css({"background-color":"red","height":"50px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: you can select the child anchor element with class `myanchor`

```
jQuery(".slc_option.wrapper.selected a.myanchor").css({"background-color":"red","height":"50px"});
```

**[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/q73x6ozs/3/)**